# Is there any way to include OR/AND inside a CSS selector for web scraping

Tags: css-selectors, scrapy

What I am trying to do, is to scrape from a website that has changed its structure through time, obtaining a `<p>` child from all `H2` OR `H3` that `.contains(RESEARCHER)`.

Currently I can do that separately with H2 or H3, but it seems to be creating some errors when I export to `.csv`. This is what I am doing:

```
'Researcher': response.css(".field-item.even h2:contains(RESEARCHER) + p ::text").extract(), 

'Researcher': response.css(".field-item.even h3:contains(RESEARCHER) + p ::text").extract(),
```

**Is there a way to combine them in a single expression?**

Comment: comma to separate classes ?

Comment: Xpath is definitely allows to do such things in a single expression. Not sure if CSS selector can do this.

Answer (score 2):

No, the best you can do is put both selectors in the same string with a comma in between:

```
response.css(".field-item.even h2:contains(RESEARCHER) + p ::text, .field-item.even h3:contains(RESEARCHER) + p ::text").extract()
```

Comment: I believe this will definitely help to patch it in the meantime. Thanks! :)